# Multiple select input doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, forms

I am building a small mobile app that uses jquery mobile and html5. It has a form with a select input in Multiple mode. Please see below:

```
<div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
    <form id = "cname" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
      <label for "id">Employee's Name:</label><br/>
       <div class="ui-select">
       <select name="id[]" id="id" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" size="10" style="height:200px;">
       <option value=""></option>
       </select><br/>

    <label for "job_id">Job's Name:</label><br/>
    <select name="job_id" id="job_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="latitued" id="latitued" value=""><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="goo_map_api" id="goo_map_api" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Clock-In" id="enviar_in" data-inline="true">

    </form>
</div>
```

The Employee's Name is the one to act as multiple. Both, Employee's Name and Job's Name are dynamically populated from a jquery script.
I have tested this script in the browser and even on live event of Dreamweaver and it works fine. I can see the windows where I can select multiple options and the I send them all to the database in array format.
But when I build the APK file and upload it to the phone(in my case a Galaxy s3) and install it, the multiple select works like a normal select without the multiple feature.

(edit) Tested also on iPad mini and samsung galaxy S2 - seems like the problem occurs for all mobile devices.
(edit2) select multiple on iPad mini with latest iOS looks like this:
[image]

Please, help!

Thanks

Comment: I guess some android devices do not support multiple select, why don't you use some plugins or bootstrap mechanism, check this one http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp this works fine on my mobile devices. Probably a library that is messing you up.

Comment: I just added an image how it looks on iPad. You can't se the choices unless you click on the select

Comment: there's an open issue on this in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1097033&q=select%20multiple&can=2